# Acceso directo a cmd de windows con una ruta determinada

Tags: batch

Buenas nunca he realizado esto y es algo que estoy intentando y no lo consigo.
Quisiera, crear un acceso directo que vaya a la consola, y este en una carpeta concreta por ejemplo **D:\proyecto\xxxx** .
Así al acceder a ese SHORTCUT me abrirá la terminal en ese PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso puedes hacerlo con un archivo `.bat`, no tanto con un acceso directo, crea tu archivo con:

```
D:
cd "D:\proyecto\xxxx"
cmd
```

Basicamente se ejecutan métodos del intérprete de comandos para hacer que cambie de unidad, cambie de directorio y ejecute el cmd.

Comment: Me viene perfecto hacerlo así muchas gracias